# How would I add access different elements in this array that I pushed inside the for loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop, replit

```
let body = document.querySelector("body");
let container = document.querySelector("#container");
//Accessing HTML Elements
let inputArray = [];
    
for (let element = 0; element < 30; element++) {
  space = document.createElement("input");
  container.appendChild(space);
  space.setAttribute("id", element);
  space.classList.add("square");
  inputArray.push(space); 
}
//For loop that creates a grid of squares and adds each square to an array 
    
document.onkeydown = event => {
  if (event.keyCode === 37) {
    for (let i = 0; i < 31; i++) {
      inputArray[i].value = ""; 
    }
  }
}
//When the left arrow key is pressed, the text in every square disappears
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not see the problem. (Apart from the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'value')` : you using loop `i<31` to the clear, but you only use `i<30` to the create).
And a little mistake: you do not define the `space` variable (I recommend to use `let`).

Comment: Oh sorry about that typo. I didn't mean to put "add" in my question. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly?

```js
const container = document.querySelector('#container')
 
const inputArray = Array.from(({length:30}),(e,i)=>
  {
  let space = container.appendChild( document.createElement('input') )
  space.id          = 
  space.placeholder = i
  space.className   = 'square'
  })
    
container.onkeydown = evt =>
  {
  if (evt.key === 'ArrowLeft' && evt.target.matches('input'))
    {
    evt.target.value = ''; 
    console.clear()
    console.log(`element.id = "${ evt.target.id }"`)
    }
  }
```

```css
.square {
  margin : .2em;
  width  : 6em;
  }
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```